# Parity of the number of roots between two zeros in a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that **f** is a polynomial.
Given that **c** and **d** are two consecutive zeros of $$f() = 0$$
show that the number of zeros between **c** and **d** of $$f'(y) + kf(y)=0  \quad ,k \in \mathbb{R}$$  is *odd* (counting multiplicity). We can use Rolle's theorem to show that there exists at least one zero between c and d. But I cannot think of a way to show the parity is odd. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are $p$ and $f$ related?

Comment: What is $p(x)$ and $k$?

Comment: @zipirovich sorry!typo. They should be all f. k is a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c$ and $d$ are two consecutive roots of $f(x)=0$,
it being a ploynomial is continuos and differentiable fr all $x \in R$. Let $g(x)=e^{kx} f(x) \implies g(c)=0=g(d)$, then we can apply Rolle's Theorem that $g'(x)=0$ will have at least one real root in $(c,d)$ and this in turn means $$f'(x)+kf(x)=0~~~~~(1)$$ has at least one real root in $(c,d)$.

Since $c$ and $d$ are consecutive roots of $f(x)=0$,
this means $f'(c)$ and $f'(d)$ will be of different sign
$f'(c)f'(d) < 0 \implies g'(c) g'(d) <0$ so (1) will have
odd number of roots in $(c,d)$ due to IVT (Intermediate value theorem)

Comment: But you still have not shown the number of zeros between c and d is odd. You only show it has at least one real root

Comment: @user43529463 We want some other informatiom.

Comment: @user43529463 I could prove it now since c and d are consecutive roots of $f(x)=0$, please see my edit.

Comment: Why will f'(c) and f'(d) be of different signs?

Comment: And why will g'(c)g'(d)<0 imply that (1) have odd number of roots in (c,d) by IVT? Thanks a lot

Comment: Then $f(x)$ between in $[c, d]$ will be like parabola on one side rising and  falling other side  or vive-versa and then $f'(c) f'(d) <0.$

Comment: If if $F(x)$ is continuous in [a,b] and  $F(a) F(b) <0$  then $F(x)=0$ will have 1, 3,5,,,,(odd number of roots). Here $F(x)=g'(x)$.

Comment: @ Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc typo in the second-last sentence.

Comment: Thanks I have removed $S$ there.

Comment: @ Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc also $f'(c)f'(d)<0$ in the second-last sentence. You missed a prime on $f$.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the typo.

Comment: Sir, what if curve of $f$ is like a smooth $W$ then $f'(c)f'(d)=0$ and your proof will be wrong??